# Multiple versions of go

Tags: go

I am trying to learn go-lng following the official docs here:
https://golang.org/doc/install

I am stuck on the step installing extra go versions. Apparently this line should install a different version of go and make the executable available in my $PATH but it's not happening:

```
go get golang.org/dl/go1.10.7
```

Instead what I see is:

```
c.craig$ go get golang.org/dl/go1.10.7
c.craig$ go1.10.7 download
-bash: go1.10.7: command not found
```

Where am I going wrong? I've tried it with a space assuming this was just a typo in the docs but even that doesn't work:

```
c.craig$ go get golang.org/dl/go1.10.7
c.craig$ go 1.10.7 download
go 1.10.7: unknown command
```

Comment: You cannot learn anything from an old version.

Comment: Wow, I'm merely trying to learn how to switch versions, old and new. I'm just getting started and yes, it is always valuable to be able to switch between old and new versions.

Comment: No, there is no point in using an old version of Go. Really. This might be useful in other programming languages, for Go it is not.

Comment: @Volker, what if I'm using a new version for my own development, but I want to contribute to a project that uses an older version?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Go version are compatible. You can contribute to an "old" project (note that there are no such in real live as everybody uses the current compiler) with your "new" Go. Just stop making up problems where  there are none. Go isn't Java, isn't C++ and not NodeJS.

Comment: There certainly are cases where you'd need to use an older version. For example, operator-sdk currently only supports 1.15, and not my current install of go1.16.

Comment: @Volker "No, there is no point in using an old version of Go. Really. This might be useful in other programming languages, for Go it is not." - I don't understand why though.

Comment: @kapad Ask yourself: What could be a sensible reason to use an old compiler? Does this reason apply to Go (in general)? No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Volker: "Ask yourself: What could be a sensible reason to use an old compiler?" > A backwards incompatible language change. and the need to compile code that was written for older syntax no longer supported. "Does this reason apply to Go (in general)?" - I don't really know enough to comment. For this or any other reason. BUT in general, I don't think there's too many variations of the original reason. It's just that.

Comment: @kapad Please be serious. I explained it already. One more time for you: Go version are compatible. There simply **are** **no** "backwards incompatible language change"s in Go and there wont be. I do know enough to comment and no, there is no reason. See https://golang.org/doc/go1compat

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/go1compat <- This is helpful. 
"There are a number of ways in which a program that compiles and runs today may fail to do so after a future point release. They are all unlikely but worth recording." - So, something there's no example of till present, and no guarantee about in future, but it later goes on to say, "Of course, for all of these possibilities, should they arise, we would endeavor whenever feasible to update the specification, compilers, or libraries without affecting existing code." Theoretical mostly, since practically, there's no such incompatibility.

Comment: @Volker source compatibility with 1.0 is great in theory, but in practice if a project's build doesn't work because of the evolving modules support mess, being able to install the old version that was known to work can save a lot of time.

Comment: One point of installing older versions is so the VS Code extension can use older versions, otherwise it keeps wanting to update go.mod of projects using older versions. A pain when you want to add features to those projects without updating their go version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The binary is installed `$HOME/go/bin` (or more accurately the `bin` directory under the path you get from `go env GOPATH`). The `go get` command doesn't update your `$PATH`, so you need to add the install directory to your `$PATH` yourself.

Answer (score 34):

After setting the following path variables in .bash_profile (do not forget to run: source ~/.bash_profile)

```bash
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/go
$ export GOBIN=$HOME/go/bin
```

Install go version in one terminal:

```bash
$ go get golang.org/dl/go1.13.15
$ go1.13.15 download
```

Now you also want to install another go version say go1.15.13 by executing the below commands (remember to set the path as told above)

```bash
$ go get golang.org/dl/go1.15.13
$ go1.15.13 download
```

Now you have two go versions installed; 1.13.15 and 1.15.13.

Say, in one terminal, you want to use version 1.13.15 so you can create an alias as below in that terminal window:

```bash
$ alias go="go1.13.15"
$ go version
go version go1.13.15 darwin/amd64
```

In another terminal you can switch to different version

```bash
$ alias go="go1.15.13"
$ go version
go version go1.15.13 darwin/amd64
```

Comment: This is the officially recommended methodology according to [golang.org](https://golang.org/doc/manage-install#installing-multiple)

Answer (score 13):

You may wish to try [Go Version Manager](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm) (`gvm`):

```
curl -s -S -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moovweb/gvm/master/binscripts/gvm-installer | bash
gvm listall
gvm install go1.10.7 [-B] 
gvm use go1.10.7 [--default]
gvm list
```

In case you want to compile from source and don't have `go` installed:

```
gvm install go1.4 -B
gvm use go1.4
#CGO_ENABLED=0
export GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=$GOROOT
gvm install go1.10.7
gvm use go1.10.7
```

In case you're getting compiling errors, you may wish to uncomment `CGO_ENABLED=0` prior to compiling from the source.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue when trying to install version 1.17.11, my base version is 1.18.2.

Followed instructions from here https://go.dev/doc/manage-install but it didn't work for me.
Then, i realized, after ran `go install golang.org/dl/go<version>@latest` (where `<version>` is the version you need), a binary file name `go<version>` will be downloaded in `$HOME/go/bin/`.

Move to `$HOME/go/bin/`, run `./go<version> download`, and version you need will be downloaded at `$HOME/sdk/`

To use the version you had just downloaded, add this line to the end of `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias go<version>=$HOME/sdk/go<version>/bin/go
```

Save and exit. Run `source ~/.bashrc` to execute it!

Answer (score 3):

Referring to the link: `https://go.dev/doc/manage-install`, step by step.
And if come up with this error:

```
$ c.craig$ go get golang.org/dl/go1.10.7
$ c.craig$ go1.10.7 download
-bash: go1.10.7: command not found
```

try to add these codes to your shell profile(like`.zshrc`):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin
```

the first path is where your base go installed, mostly is `/usr/local/go/bin`.
And then the error would be fixed.

Comment: Annoying that the guide from the go page as it's now doesn't work out of the box on macOS. I assume it's the same on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I also found useful using this tool to switch between versions:
[Freshgo - https://nikfot.github.io/freshgo/](https://nikfot.github.io/freshgo/)
It is a go binary and easy to install (linux).

I installs go versions from the source easily and can keep a backup of your go source files so if you switch between versions you save some little time from go pkg downloads.

Easy as that:

```
freshgo select -v 1.19
```

I also installed it in my shell to check for latest versions, with a ready script:

```
echo "${PATH to freshgo repo}/check_ver.sh" >>  ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as yours, after I knew that go is back-compatible, I copy the /usr/local/go/bin/go to /usr/local/go/bin/go{version}.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend https://github.com/stefanmaric/g as an alternative of `gvm` in the field of go version manager.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am quite late to the party, but being really fed up with how multiple versions should be managed in Go, I decided to build a simple CLI that does the trick easily.

https://github.com/VassilisPallas/gvs/

I released it a couple of days ago, which means there are a few things that need to be added as features. But feel free to reach out to me if you see any required improvements/new features.

Answer (score 0):

what about [goup-rs](https://github.com/thinkgos/goup-rs), it wirte in rust, single binary but only depend `git`.

```bash
$ goup install
[2024-01-30T00:38:48Z INFO ] Installing go1.21.6 ...
[2024-01-30T00:38:48Z INFO ] Unpacking /home/thinkgo/.goup/go1.21.6/go1.21.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz ...
[2024-01-30T00:38:48Z INFO ] go1.21.6 installed in /home/thinkgo/.goup/go1.21.6
[2024-01-30T00:38:48Z INFO ] Default Go is set to 'go1.21.6'
$ goup list
| VERSION | ACTIVE |
|---------|--------|
| 1.21.6  |   *    |
$ go env GOROOT
/home/thinkgo/.goup/current
$ go version
go version go1.21.6 linux/amd64
$ GOUP_GO_HOST=https://golang.google.cn goup install 1.21.6
```

Answer (score -4):

For Mac users it's easier and I guess for Linux users should be similar, you just need to:

1. use a modern version of GO i.e. >= 1.12
2. make sure you can run `go version`
3. browse the version you need: https://go.dev/dl/ lets say you want to download `go1.13.15` you can run the following command(I think the @latest is optional): `go install golang.org/dl/go1.13.15@latest`, if nothing happens then everything is ok.
4. beacuse you need to update your PATH you can either do it or open a new terminal.
5. run the command: `go1.13.15 download`
6. Now you can find a new directory in $HOME/sdk/go1.13.15 thats where your new instalation of GO resides.
7. update your GOROOT env var to work with your workspace with the following command: `export GOROOT=$HOME/sdk/go1.13.15`
8. Finally type `go version` you should see

```
go version go1.13.15 darwin/amd64
```